# How to "move" balances between wallets?

Tags: go-ethereum

There is a "move" command in Bitcoin, Litecoin, Dash etc. which lets you move balances between wallets in your node without paying a transaction fee.

I wonder if there is a similar command in geth? I'm currently using geth and transferring balances between wallets with eth.sendTransaction command which costs me extra tx fee.

Comment: Does this have a production reason or a debug reason?

Comment: production reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Bitcoin's "move" command is an off-chain operation; this is why it can be done for free. It is a logical regrouping of address balances. An account in Bitcoin is comprised of one or more addresses. A send command in Bitcoin and Ethereum is an on-chain operation that actually changes the balances of addresses.

Based on my understanding, the "move" command in Bitcoin and friends probably operates quite differently than you might think. (Simplifying a bit) in Bitcoin, there is a concept of an "address" which is the same as an address in Ethereum: addresses are alphanumeric identifiers that have amounts of bitcoin (or ether) associated with them. In Bitcoin, you send bitcoin *to* an address, but the clients I'm familiar with generally let you interact with "accounts" (I think it's the same thing as what you mean by "wallet"). An account is a collection of addresses, each of which may contain bitcoin. Unlike Ethereum, when you send bitcoin, you must spend ALL of the bitcoin that was received in a particular transaction. Thus, to preserve pseudonymity, it is common to send the change back to a *change address* rather than the originating address. This makes it harder to determine how much was sent. For example:

- Address A (owned by Alice) receives 3 bitcoin in transaction TX1.
- Address A (owned by Alice) receives 5 bitcoin in transaction TX2.
- Alice wants to send 1 bitcoin to Bob.
- Alice signs a transaction, TX3, whereby TX1 is spent in the following way:

  - 1 bitcoin sent to address B (owned by Bob).
  - 2 bitcoin sent to address C (owned by Alice).
- Alice wants to send 2.5 bitcoin to Charles.
- Alice signs a transaction, TX4, whereby TX2 is spent in the following way:

  - 2.5 bitcoin sent to address D (owned by Charles)
  - 2.5 bitcoin sent to address E (owned by Alice).

Now, Alice controls keys for the following addresses: A, C, and E. They contain 0, 2, and 2.5 bitcoins, respectively. Now, Alice can decide to create a fake identity, Alicerino. She can assign address E to this new account for Alicerino by using "move" and remove the private keys for E from the normal Alice account. Previously, if Alice wanted to send more than 2.5 bitcoins to someone, her wallet could take bitcoins from addresses C or E, but now it won't. For example, if Alice had NOT "move"d the bitcoins, she could send 3 bitcoins to Daryl like this:

- Alice signs a transaction, TX5, whereby the outputs TX1-C and TX2-E are spent in the following way:

  - 3 bitcoin sent to address F (owned by Daryl)
  - 2 bitcoin sent to address G (owned by Alice).

Notice that all of this happens off-chain. Ethereum doesn't allow merging of address balances like that, so there is no equivalent. If you need to combine two or more address balances to make up a particular amount in Ethereum, the receiving party needs to know that the multiple addresses should be treated as coming from the same person and/or the amount from one or more addresses is sent to one address prior to performing the transaction.

A weird fruit-based analogy:
If you have a basket of 10 oranges, you could say to your friend, "feel free to eat any orange with a sticker on it." This is equivalent to having 10 addresses in Bitcoin with a bitcoin each; your "friend" here is a Bitcoin wallet. The oranges with a sticker are account A and the ones without are account B. Thus, multiple addresses may belong to each account. But you can freely change whether or not there is a sticker on the fruit. At least until someone eats the fruit (your bitcoin is spent).