# Parity send local without fee

Tags: ether, parity

I created some accounts on my computer use Parity. I'm sent ETH to this accounts.

Now, i want move all balance of all accounts to new account **without fee**. **I can?**

Of course, the new account in local
.

Comment: If you're on the mainnet, it's impossible to send transactions without fees

Comment: What do you mean by "*local*"?

Comment: All transactions have an associated gas cost with it. If you are doing this on local, then you won't actually be paying for it but one of the accounts will be responsible for the transaction gas, even on local.

Comment: Are you referring to this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44460/how-to-move-balances-between-wallets/44463 ?